# Is the F statistic value the same as the residual error term?

Tags: anova, error

A guide for authors says that a residual error term must be included when data are analyzed using ANOVA.

Does this mean including the F value and degrees of freedom? If not, then what does this mean?

Comment: Consider how you calculate the F-stat.

Comment: Thanks! So instead, it is the residual from the random effects (eg covariance parameter estimates in SAS)?